# Ionic framework compile error (Components not recognized)

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on a project using the ionic framework (with angular) to make a mobile application. I have worked with ionic before in the same environment and same directory with no issues. The error mentioned is the component not found error for all ionic components in every html file of the project. For some reason, the error seems to disappear for some time after the node_modules directory is deleted and reinstalled again after the cache is cleared (although this only works temporarily and is not a permanent fix). This makes me feel that there is no issue with the code itself, but possibly some issues with the dependencies. Has someone experienced a similar issue before, I would really appreciate the help? [error shown by VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrVHx.png)

Comment: Which ionic version is the code written in?

Comment: I have the same error on VS Code since I moved to ionic 6 a few month ago. But it runs without issue, in dev, prod or build modes. I guess it may be an issue with a VS Code plugin? Angular Language Server maybe?

Comment: I am running ionic version 6.18.1 if its of any use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my project (angular 12, ionic 6) :

- Go to VSCode settings
- Search for view-engine
- Uncheck "Use legacy View Engine language service".

[image: Disable legacy view engine for angular ionic]